# How to set the color for the placeholders in a format string

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, color-scheme

I have Resharper installed in Visual Studio, and am using the standard 'dark' theme, and somehow I managed to change something so that the '{0}' characters in a format string are no longer colored differently than the rest of the string.

For example, in the following line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", Environment.UserName);
```

The quoted string is entirely the same rust color (as it appears in this SO editor), whereas previously the '{0}' was highlighted with a bright greenish color.

**EDIT**

The settings under 'Resharper Format String Item' appear correct:

[image]

Also, the R# Code Annotations is set to JetBrains.Annotations, and is set as the default:

[image]

Would some other setting override this? Is there an easy way to just reset everything back to defaults?

Comment: Options -> Environment -> General -> Fonts and Colors -> choose 'Resharper Format String Item' from Display Items

Comment: Thank you, but that is set correctly (bright green). Not sure why it isn't working, something else must be overriding it. :(

Comment: That's weird. Have you tried changing the theme and setting it back again?

Comment: @JoonasKoski Yep. :(

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Any movement on this?

Comment: Hahahaha! Nabs!

Answer (score 1):

I've found the element in the change font dialog. It was a nightmare, hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you've already noted, Resharper knows what color to use for this according to the setting here:

*Options* > *Environment* > *General* > *Fonts and Colors* — the **Resharper Format String Item** setting.

However, R# knows which *methods* to apply that color to by using its internal **Code Annotations** feature.

Check under *Resharper* > *Options* > *Code Inspection* > *Code Annotations* , and make sure that JetBrains.Annotations is checked, and that it is selected as the default annotation namespace at the bottom of that screen.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, those settings are also set correctly. I'm really stumped by this one!

Comment: Pretty strange. If you change {0} to {1}, does R# warn about a non-existent argument?

Comment: It suggests that the problem does rest with Resharper not recognizing the code annotations for some reason, so it doesn't know that the arguments are format parameters. You may be able to confirm this further by following R# help here: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp80/Code_Analysis__String_Formatting_Methods.html